# How to store large 20 million digit number in php?

Tags: php, biginteger

I searched and I found that I can use number_format function in php. But it can't even store 1 million digits . I am getting output as inf.
Can someone help me please. If it's not possible in php then can it be done in C++ or Java ?

Update: I am using GMP but when I run script browser sent me response as "this site can't be reached, connection was reset". I disabled max execution time but it gives me same error.
What should I do? Do I need to do any other changes in configuration?

Comment: What do you need to do with the number? If you just need to store it you could possibly just use a string.

Comment: I want to divide that number by other small numbers so I can't  store it as string. Please give me other solution

Comment: Have you looked into any of the [math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php) extensions that are [available](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php)?

Answer (score -1):

There is *bigint* choice in phpmyadmin
Laravel has that too, and you can do it in terminal

bigint is great but rarely used

---

**Updated**

you can use float and set value limit

[image: In this picture I used float and defined the value limit to 20]

In this picture I used float and defined the value limit to 20

Hope that helps

Comment: MySQL's BigInt can hold numbers up to 2^64-1, which is not enough for the millions of digits OP wants to store.